# What's the intuition of the relation between fibonacci-like sequences and the proportion used to obtain the golden ratio?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Everyone knows that we can obtain the golden ratio from the following proportion:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a+b}{a}$$

We also know that we get ${\phi}^N$ when we try to find a function that satisfies the following Fibonacci sequence characteristic:
$$A^{N+2}=A^{N+1} + A^N$$

Algebraically, I know why they are related(both the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ in the first eq and the constant $A$ in the second eq are solutions to the same second degree equation: $x²=x+1$). However, I have absolutely no intution for why that would be the case.
Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: You will be perhaps interested by the so-called "metallic sequences" considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262735/305862)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that it answers my question unless I am missing something.